# How can I resolve the "Could not start video source" error in my Kurento JavaScript WebRTC application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, kurento

I encountered an issue when making cross-browser calls between Chrome and Firefox users in a WebRTC application. User 2 (using Firefox) receives an error message in the Chrome console: "script.js: Error: Could not start video source," preventing the display of both the user's own video and the video from User 1.

I am testing the WebRTC app locally by opening two browsers on the same machine. The WebSocket is initialized with the following URL: const wsUrl = "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/one2one";

Both User 1 and User 2 have granted permission to access the microphone and camera in their browser settings and also from  windows 10 settings. The Chrome and Firefox versions used support the necessary WebRTC features, and the signaling server is functioning correctly, properly handling the offer and answer exchange.stun tun server i have added alredy(as of now public one not yet tried coturn).As i am using kurento utils i am not using getUserMedia().

Interestingly, the same error message occurs when User 1 (Chrome) initiates a call to User 2 (Firefox). This issue persists regardless of the browser configuration.

It seems that the error is specifically related to the video source and arises when establishing the WebRTC connection between Chrome and Firefox browsers. The same issue occurs when using two Chrome browsers for testing.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. The application is being developed in Node.js with Kurento media server.

Note: As i am testing localy i am not using ssl and https.My kurento docker image is running on a remote desktop and docker image is running fine

i am following the code in kurento official docs

https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html